# Send multiple arrays via Ajax in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to build an API with 1 string and 5 arrays as parameters:

```
public List<HomeClass> GetData(string id, string[] price, string[] type, string[] sqft, string[] beds, string[] baths)
{
}
```

I am using jQuery to call this API like so:

```
var priceArray = [];
    var typeArray = [];
    var sqftArray = [];
    var bedroomsArray = [];
    var bathroomsArray = [];

function searchInventory(community, price, type, sqft, bedrooms, bathrooms) {

$.get('/api/HomesAPI/' + community + '/' + price + '/' + type + '/' + sqft + '/' + bedrooms + '/' + bathrooms).then(function (result) {

});

}

searchInventory(getURLParameter(window.location.pathname.split('/'))[2], priceArray, typeArray, sqftArray, bedroomsArray, bathroomsArray);
```

So I am passing 1 string and 5 arrays, but my API is not being called, if I change the array to strings in both .NET and jQuery, it works just fine, but not with arrays. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my route

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{price}/{type}/{sqft}/{beds}/{baths}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: I'd think a route like that is going to expect a single value, not an array.  You might need to make the arrays query parameters that aren't part of your path/route.  Ask yourself this: What will the url look like?  For example, A select multiple tag functions by passing the value multiple times.  Which could be a list of string in your controller.  ( api/Home/17?X=1&X=2&X=3&X=4 ).  See, in that example it can not be in the route.  Not every parameter needs be Route defined.

Comment: this is an odd way to call an API. Normally you'd have all these things as one "SearchParams" object, or something like that. And just call "/api/HomesAPI/Search" and pass the SearchParams object as data - which in the case of a GET would be serialised onto the end of the URI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `$.param` method, in order to serialize your `object`.

> `$.param` method create a serialized representation of an array, a
>   plain object, or a jQuery object suitable for use in a URL query
>   string or Ajax request.

```
$.get('/api/HomesAPI',$.param({id:community, price:price, type:type, sqft:sqft, beds:bedrooms , baths:bathrooms },true),function (data) {

});
```

or you can pass an object to server.

Also, you have to use `traditional:true` property in order to use the `traditional` style of [parameters serialization](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/).

```
var data = {
   id: community,
   price:price,
   type:type,
   sqft:sqft,
   beds:bedrooms,
   baths:bathrooms
};
```

Ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/HomesAPI',
    type: "GET",
    data:data,
    traditional:true
});
```

**Note**: You do not need to use another `route`.

Comment: Now my URL looks like this `api/HomesAPI?{"id":"Fallingwaters","price":[],"type":[],"sqft":[],"beds":[],"baths":[]}` and now it says 404, URL not found

Comment: Have you removed your custom route ?

Comment: Have you tried the method with `JSON.stringify()` ?

Comment: @user979331, i updated my answer.I tested both methods and works for me.

Comment: Both ways did not work, I am going to update my question